# Drag & Drop Event in Quilljs

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm fairly new at Quill.

I want to make a custom module or extended function that handles drag and drop event.
I want to detect the dropped text, and if it's an image url, I want to insert 'img' tag instead of 'a' tag.

Currently, Quill is adding 'a' tag for dropped url, but I cannot find related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special handling for drag and drop at the moment. What you're seeing is simply native browser behavior.